# Stability order of chelate complexes of nickel and iron

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, stability

> Which stability order is correct?
>
> 1. $\ce{[Ni(en)2]^2+} > \ce{[Ni(dmg)2]}$
> 2. $\ce{[Fe(edta)]^2-} > \ce{[Fe(en)3]^3+}$

In the first case I think the stability depends upon the strength of the ligand so is $\ce{en}$ stronger than $\ce{dmg}$ to form a more stable compound? As the oxidation state of nickel is same for both the cases.

In the second case the oxidation state of iron is +2 and +3, respectively. But I am confused if the metal with higher oxidation state is more stable or the metal with lower oxidation state is more stable?

Does stability depends upon the number of chelating groups?

Comment: In general, metal with higher oxidation state forms more stable complex.

Comment: But that does not appear to be the case in the second example where +2 is more stable than +3 of fe